# How can I use an image resource referenced by a MediaWiki extension's CSS?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

### The Question

How can I add images to a MediaWiki extension in a way that they can be referenced by css files registered as `ResourceModules`?

### The Situation

I'm developing a MediaWiki extension which leverages a [third party tool](https://leafletjs.com/) and I'm including a copy of that tool as part of the extension's resources.

The tool has js and css, which I am including like so:

```
...
  "ResourceModules": {
    "ext.leaflet": {
      "scripts": "ext.leaflet/leaflet.js",
      "styles": "ext.leaflet/leaflet.css"
    }
  },
...
```

The third party tool *also* includes an image directory which includes various images referenced by `leaflet.css`, but I don't know where to put that in a way that MediaWiki will serve it alongside the CSS / JS.

The image url is resolving to `{SERVER}/ext.leaflet/images/marker-icon.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the image assets in an image folder in your extension folder, and reference it in your CSS in a relative fashion.

Take a look at the Echo extension for example:

The image is referenced like this in the css

`background-image: url( ../../images/pending.gif );`

https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-Echo/search?q=pending.gif

And stored here:
`{SERVER}/extensions/Echo/images`

https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-Echo/tree/master/images

The CSS is registered as `ResourceModule` on this line

https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-Echo/blob/97771e3369b7949db242f72551ac6efe803881e5/extension.json#L460

In your JS you could use `mw.config.get('wgExtensionAssetsPath')` in my case this returns `/extensions`